# document.execCommand paste not working in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

`document.execCommand` paste not working, i.e it works only when a selection has been made and it replaces the selected contents, otherwise no change is made. By the way I am using a `contenteditable` div element where I am trying to do this.

In all browsers it fails, I am using it on clicking a particular `li` element of a `ul`.

```
 <ul>
  <li> 
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="paste();"><span>Paste</span></a> 
  </li> 
 </ul>
```

Where paste is the function where I use: `document.execCommand('paste',false,null);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [document.execCommand  paste not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717204/document-execcommand-paste-not-working)

Comment: More information needed. Which browsers does it fail in? How are you triggering the command (e.g. are you using a button?)

Comment: in all browsers it fails, i am using it on clicking a particular li element of a ul. (Code) 
 <ul>
 <li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="paste();"><span>Paste</span></a>
 </li>
 </ul>

where paste is the function where is use :  document.execCommand('paste',false,null);

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla (Opera too) requires special [security setting](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/midasdemo/securityprefs.html).

[Browsers compatibility.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html)

[Check this (preferably in IE)](http://jsfiddle.net/aF7m7/2/). While you click the link, the focus is changing and the browser wants to paste data into that link. I hope it will help you.